# Excel VBA code to password protect back up file

Tags: excel, vba

Good Afternoon,

I have the below code that I'm using to create a back up of my workbook upon saving.  It is saving to a separate location and everything appears to be working correctly.  The below code is entered for the workbook instead of individual sheets.

Can anyone tell me how I can create a password protection on the back up file the below code is generating?

I'm fairly new to VBA scripting but I have seen a function to create password protection with the save as function but I don't know how to incorporate that into my code below.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.EnableEvents = False

thisPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
myName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1))
ext = Right(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, "."))
backupdirectory = "Backup"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not FSO.FolderExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & backupdirectory) Then
    FSO.CreateFolder (ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & backupdirectory)
End If

T = Format(Now, "mmm dd yyyy hh mm ss")
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs thisPath & "\" & backupdirectory & "\" & myName & " " & T & "." & ext

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an Excel file called `master.xlsm`.  This tiny sub:

1.saves the file
2.saves a backup copy of the file with protection
3.quits Excel

```
Sub SaveAndBackup()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="backup.xlsm", Password:="secret"
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Change this  to meet your own file-naming and location needs.

Comment: @StillLearningHowtoCode  then remove the `Application.Quit`

Comment: Any idea how to accomplish this without closing the original file as in all likelihood our team will be saving the file as they make edits, not always at the time they want to close it.  As a result, i'd like to version my backup to coincide with each time they save the file.

Comment: @StillLearningHowtoCode Consider **reversing the order** of the saves.  First do the backup save and then re-save with the original filename..........make sure when you re-save with the original name, that you do so without the password.